# Why won't my program in MySQL let me Load my file?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm new to mySQL and my professor is asking us to make some tables and upload a text file with data for those tables into our programs, but when I tried following the MySQL tutorial to do so, it would give me he error code 3948 "Loading local data is disabled: his bus be enabled on both the client and server sides". Can anyone help me with this? I'm so lost.

I tried looking up tutorials and videos but none of them helped.

Comment: It's not `his bus be enabled`, it's `this must be enabled` Please use copy/paste so you copy the exact error message.

Comment: And if you just google the error message you'll find the answers.